# Probability of meeting the right partner

Tags: probability

Suppose a dating service has men with the following characteristics and relative frequencies:

Bald $(B)$ $0.67$

Eyeglasses $(E)$ $0.44$

Contacts $(C)$ $0.29$

Smoker $(S)$ $0.12$

They can be present or absent independently and occur simultaneously, except that glasses and contacts never occur together. Candidates are selected at random.

What is the probability of selecting a non-bald, non-smoking man?

My thoughts are that it can occur in 3 ways:
$$B^c \cap S^c \cap C \cap E^c $$
$$B^c \cap S^c \cap C^c \cap E $$
$$B^c \cap S^c \cap C^c \cap E^c $$

Using the independence property, this gives:

$$P(B^c)P(S^c)P(C)P(E^c) + P(B^c)P(S^c)P(C^c)P(E) + P(B^c)P(S^c)P(C^c)P(E^c)$$

which is 0.253345. However, if I look at it this way:

$$P(B^c \cap S^c) = P(B^c)P(C^c)$$

Then I get 0.2904. Shouldn't both ways give the same result?

Comment: Your assumption of independence is wrong here! Is non-bald certainly implies non-smoker? Looking at the probabilities I can say no!

Comment: The problem statement says they are independent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C and E are NOT independent.   $P(C \mbox{ and } E^c) = P(C)$, $P(C^c \mbox{ and } E^c) = 1-.44-.29$, and $P(E \mbox{ and } C^c) = P(E)$.

So the second way of calculating it is correct, while the first way should be modified.

Comment: Thanks! Does it make a difference if instead I ask for non-smoking and no eyeglasses?

Comment: The easiest way to do Non-smoking and no eyeglasses would be $P(S^c)P(E^c)$, but you can also do $P(S^c)P(E^C)P(B) + P(S^c)P(E^c)P(B^c)$.  Or you could go $P(S^c)P(C) + P(S^c)P((C\cup E)^c)$

Comment: In the second way of doing it, why isn't there any terms with $C$ or $C^c$ in them?

Comment: If you're referring to $P(S^c)P(C)+P(S^c)P((C∪E)^c)$, there is a $P(C)$ there. But anyways, if you say no eyeglasses there are two possibilities for that.  Either the individual has contacts (C) or they have nothing ($(C\cup E)^c)$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough information to give an answer.

If every man who smokes is bald then the proportion of non-bald, non-smoking men is $1-0.67=0.33$

Conversely, if no man who smokes is bald then the proportion of non-bald, non-smoking men is $1 - 0.67 - 0.12 = 0.21$.

To get an answer one way or the other we need to know the proportion of men who are both bald *and* smoke.

Then the answer can be found using the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: The proportion of both is P(non-bald)P(non-smoking), by the problem statement that they are independent, isn't it?